# Wordpress loop through parent page and display the_content() not working as expected

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm trying to loop through parent pages and display the title, content and permalink. Everything is working as expected, except the_content() isn't displaying anything at all. I'm placing this within a custom page template so I can use it for other pages throughout my site. Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

```
$pageID = $wp_query->post->ID;

$child_pages = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'      => 'page',
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'post_parent'    => $pageID,
    'no_found_rows'  => true
    ) );

while ( $child_pages->have_posts() ) : $child_pages->the_post();

the_title();
the_content(); // Also tried apply_filters, didn't work :(
echo '<br>';
get_the_post_thumbnail();

endwhile;

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Please use get_the_content(get_the_ID()) instead the_content(). I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks brother, I'll give a shot and see what happens.

Comment: @SajidAnwar doesn't work, it still shows only the title with no content beneath it.